# Sort Devexprees grid by specific Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, devexpress

I want to sort my devexprees react datagrid by value that I receive from a server so the received row would be in the top of the grid, Hi I can do it?

Here is my code:

```
    <DataGrid
        dataSource={dataSource}
        showBorders
        className="mb-5"
        onContentReady={contentReady}
        remoteOperations={true}
        columnChooser={{
            enabled: true
        }}
        allowColumnResizing={true}
        filterRow={{
            visible: true
        }}
        showColumnLines={true}
        selection={{ mode: 'single' }}
        searchPanel={{ visible: true }}
        pager={{
            showPageSizeSelector: true,
            allowedPageSizes: [25, 50, 100],
            showInfo: true
        }}
        stateStoring={{
            enabled: true,
            type: 'localStorage',
            storageKey: 'KeysGrid'
        }}
    >
        <Editing
            mode="row"
            allowDeleting={true}
            allowUpdating={true} />
        <Export enabled={true} />
        <Sorting descendingText="id"  />
        <Column dataField="passId" caption="№" width={150} so />
        <Column dataField="roomNumber" caption="№ " width={120} />
        <Column dataField="floor" caption="" width={80} />
        <Column dataField="description" caption="" width={140} />
        <Column dataField="comment" caption="" width={140} />
        <Column dataField="active" caption="" width={140} />
    </DataGrid>
```

I know i need to reset some sorting configuration like this

```
grid.columnOption(5, 'sortOrder', void 0);
```

but I don`t see it in documentation, can any help please

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you friend.

[Custom Sorting](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/#calculateSortValue)